# How do I listen to a Document with Auth UID being its reference?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my search there is some ways to do this. One way is to use `FutureBuilder` and `StreamBuilder` at the same time. But I want to avoid this nesting StreamBuilder inside FutureBuilder?

I tried to create a method and call this from stream builder.

```
    _getData() async{

  FirebaseUser user =  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String uid = user.uid.toString();
var snapshots = 
Firestore.instance.collection('userinfo').document(uid).snapshots();
      return snapshots;
}


@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Retrieve Text Input'),
  ),
  body: new Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
    child:  new StreamBuilder(
        stream: _getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var userDocument = snapshot.data;
             return new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                        initialValue:  userDocument["name"].toString(),
                        //controller: _AdContr,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Name',
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                          ),
                          //fillColor: Colors.green
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20),
                      TextFormField(
                        //initialValue: Text(userDocument["Surname"]).toString(),
                        //controller: _AdContr,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Surname',
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                            borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                          ),
                          //fillColor: Colors.green
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
          }
        }),
   ),
 );
}
```

But I  am getting this error:

> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Stream'

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will **need to** nest a `StreamBuilder` inside a `FutureBuilder` because you will need to await the user from FirebaseAuth before being able to get the stream. However, this *is not bad* at all.
This is how Flutter works: nesting widgets.

```dart
..., child: FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) return Container();
          return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance.collection('userinfo').document(snapshot.data.uid).snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();
              return Column(...);
            },
          );
        })
```

Another aspect that is crucial for this to work is that you *always* return a widget from any builder. If you do not return a widget to a builder in Flutter, your app will break, i.e. a runtime exception will be thrown.